# Should I use Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm about to embark on a very large front end build project, and probably reusing the same grid for many sites. The back-end developers in my team are raving and raving about Bootstrap and how we should be using it.

I've started using it and it's very good, but our grid has become more complex than the Bootstrap one. So I've drilled into the LESS files and added some of my own rules and modified the responsive grid. I also might need to change and add the media queries in there.

So my question is, considering that I'm having to change and customize Bootstrap quite a bit, would it be **best practice** to do this or create my grid/framework from scratch?

Comment: I think this question is too likely to solicit opinion rather than get you a factual answer. IMO I would not change the bootstrap CSS but rather add my own CSS that overrides the styles. Twitter Bootstrap provides more than just a responsive grid so it depends how much of it you want to use. This is your project and nobody here can know the complexity of it. So for that reason I am voting to close as not constructive.

Comment: Thanks My Head Hurts, I'm going to take yours and perikis's (answer below) advice with overriding, but not changing the bootstrap core. I'll also comment out any parts of the varibales.less file I don't use in order to keep it slim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that you use bootstrap and apply customizations per you needs. In our case, we provide a couple of additional .less files, and @import them in bootstrap.less. We use one for variables, imported right below variables.less and one for classes, imported at the end of the boostrap.less list. This way, you ensure that you can override both variables and classes, and include your own, while at the same time you remain compatible with future bootstrap updates

Comment: Thanks periklis, I think taking this approach will work. I'll comment out the parts that I don't need in the varibales.less file and then include my own modifications as overrides.

Comment: ok, but you don't have to comment out anything, the approach above just works - only that it results in a somewhat bigger and redundant css file

Answer (score 1):

first check how many things you have to build in twitter bootstrap to match it with your framework. i think twitter bootstrap comes with responsive grids so you don't have to work with lots of stuff + Less is there to customize the way you want. check http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html

if the no. of functionality's are too much then think in terms of project budget and in future how twitter bootstrap can be useful. it will answer everything i guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look with jqgrid http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html, It can be customised to a great extent..with little tweak we can integrate that with BootStrap